# How to get json value get in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I dynamically created image tag using javascript and I used one JSON file. Image tag click called `onclick` function `getMode` function. this function parameter `id` only I can use in the parameter. but I can not use id and objMaterial two parameters. I need JSON objMaterial values also How to get?

```
function floorGridToolList(jsonPath, parentID){

            document.getElementById('floorTexture').style.display = 'block';

            var path = $.getJSON(jsonPath, function (jsonObjectList) {

              for (i = 0; i < jsonObjectList.objects.length; i++) {

                var imgTag = document.createElement('img');
                imgTag.setAttribute('src', jsonObjectList.objects[i].iconImage);
                imgTag.setAttribute('id', jsonObjectList.objects[i].id);
                imgTag.setAttribute("title", jsonObjectList.objects[i].iconTitle);

                imgTag.onclick = function () {
        //getMode(this.id);  It's working
        getMode(this.id, jsonObjectList.objects[i].objMaterial); //Error                    };
                parentID.appendChild(imgTag);
                }

         });

    }
```

`MY JSON`

```
{
  "categoryName": "Floor",
    "objects": [{
        "id": "darkgrass",
        "iconImage": "models/floor/DarkGrass/darkGrassIcon.png",
        "iconTitle": "Dark Grass",
        "objMaterial":"models/floor/DarkGrass/darkGrassTexture.jpg",
        "color": ""
    },{
        "id": "lightgrass",
        "iconImage": "models/floor/LightGrass/lightGrassIcon.png",
        "iconTitle": "Light Grass",
        "objMaterial":"models/floor/LightGrass/lightGrassTexture.jpg",
        "color": ""
    },{
        "id": "soilbrownmud",
        "iconImage": "models/floor/SoilBrownMud/soilBrownMudIcon.png",
        "iconTitle": "Light Grass",
        "objMaterial":"models/floor/SoilBrownMud/soilBrownMudTexture.jpg",
        "color": ""
    }]
}
```

'Error'

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objMaterial' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.imgTag.onclick (objectDraw.js:1219)
imgTag.onclick @ objectDraw.js:1219

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: I need id base json file objMaterial value how to get? getMode(this.id, jsonObjectList.objects[id].objMaterial); this method wrong. How to this.id based objMaterial value get? @zabusa

Comment: please input the expected output to the question with correct format

Comment: You are passing id as index to the object array there in getMode(this.id, jsonObjectList.objects[id].objMaterial). It should be objects[i].objMaterial

Answer (score 0):

```
getMode(this.id, jsonObjectList.objects[i].objMaterial) //try using this
```

you got undefined because in your json the objects is an array with keys 0,1,2 etc.. you tried to point at "id" which does not have a corresponding value in array. hence the undefined error.

Comment: I used getMode(this.id, jsonObjectList.objects[i].objMaterial). runtime i get this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objMaterial' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.imgTag.onclick objectDraw.js:1197)' @Rubin Johny

Comment: are you trying to get the individual ids from the object array ?

Comment: jsonObjectList.objects[i].id // when used inside the loop, this should return each id.

Answer (score 0):

You have  to save the objMaterial also in the image tag like this :

```
imgTag.setAttribute("objMaterial", jsonObjectList.objects[i].objMaterial);
```

And then you can retrieve it using `this.objMaterial` in your getMode function.

Comment: imgTag.setAttribute("objMaterial", jsonObjectList.objects[i].objMaterial); and next getMode(this.id, this.objMaterial) i used. it's also  undefined.@mayank jain

Comment: can you share the exact error that you are getting here.